# Get the maximum value of a variable in C

Tags: c

Is there a function in C that returns the maximum value of a variable like this (I will name the function "maxvalue" in example below)?

```
int a;
printf("%d", maxvalue(a)); // 32767
unsigned int b;
printf("%d", maxvalue(b)); // 65535
```

So basically the function returns values like `INT_MAX` when the variable is signed INT, UINT_MAX when unsigned int, etc.

Comment: Might be possible with the new C11 with [type-generic macros](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html)

Comment: C functions take as argument values, not types. For an unsigned integer type `T`, you can always compute the maximum value of that type with `((T)-1)`. For a signed integer type, I do not know any portable solution.

Comment: @Joachim - definitely possible.  My answer has a complete example for the OP's case.  My system has 32-bit `int` types, so the answers are larger, but it's the same idea.

Comment: @CarlNorum It's even possible without C11; see (the second half of) my answer.

Comment: @CarlNorum ... or not; see my afterthought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a function is not defined by the C standard library. You can try defining a macro that calculates it:

```
#define MAX_VALUE(a) (((unsigned long long)1 << (sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT)) - 1)
```

When using it, be careful it is assigned to a type large enough. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define IS_TYPE_SIGNED(a) ((a-1) < 0)
#define MAX_VALUE_UNSIGNED(a) (((unsigned long long)1 << \
        (sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT)) - 1)
#define MAX_VALUE_SIGNED(a) (MAX_VALUE_UNSIGNED(a) >> 1)
#define MAX_VALUE(a) (IS_TYPE_SIGNED(a) ? \
        MAX_VALUE_SIGNED(a) : MAX_VALUE_UNSIGNED(a))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    signed int j = 0;

    printf("%llu\n", MAX_VALUE(i));
    printf("%llu\n", MAX_VALUE(j));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This prints out:

```
4294967295
2147483647
```

Comment: And it needs a `-1`. Nice near-answer to the question anyway.

Comment: It does work on signed types - running that program above prints out 4294967296 on my machine, which sounds about right.

Comment: @Mike - no it doesn't work for signed types.  I voted down your answer because it's wrong.  `4294967295` is almost certainly the max for an *unsigned* type.  MAX_VALUE for a signed integer should probably be giving back `2147483647`.  The maximum signed 32-bit number is `0x7fffffff`, not, `0xffffffff`, which your answer gives.

Comment: Sorry - read your parentheses wrong.  Your program gives back `0x8000000`, which is still wrong, but in a different way.  It's neither `INT_MAX`, *nor* `UINT_MAX`.  I guess it's `-INT_MIN`?  There are weird macro errors, too - your `(unsigned long long)` cast just casts the `1` in your macro, not the whole result, which is the only reason it appears to work at all - you'd get a negative result if you had parentheses around your macro expansion.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I've tried my best to fix it. I think that should work. We can shift the cast into the macro. Not sure what can be done about how it is split into two macros.

Comment: Close, you're off-by-one on the signed result.  Now your answer doesn't answer the question, though, since you need separate macros.

Comment: Now you require the variable to be set to `0` for it to work?

Comment: `((a-1) < 0)` -- First, your macro parameter isn't guarded against misparsing -- you should parenthesize it. Second, there's no way, no how that you can tell whether a value (nor lvalue) has a signed or unsigned type ... you need the type as a parameter. See my answer (to a related question).

Comment: (stupid OS time limit ... "I take that back") ... See my answer for a complete solution using that idea.

Comment: Or not so complete ... see my afterthought, which makes a general portable solution impossible.

Comment: `(((unsigned long long)1 << (sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT)) - 1)` will not work for `a's` of type `(unsigned) long long` because of the overflow in the shift operator count. It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it quite easily with a [C11 type-generic expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Changes_from_C99):

```
#define maxvalue(type) _Generic(type, int: INT_MAX, \
                                      unsigned int: UINT_MAX)
```

It's not a function, but I think it does what you want.  Here's a simple example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define maxvalue(type) _Generic(type, int: INT_MAX, \
                                      unsigned int: UINT_MAX)

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int ui;

    printf("%u\n", maxvalue(i));
    printf("%u\n", maxvalue(ui));

    return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
$ clang -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 example.c -o example
$ ./example 
2147483647
4294967295
```

My answers are larger than yours because my system has 32-bit integers.  You appear to have a 16-bit machine.

Comment: I didn't know you could get c to tell you the type of a variable. Neat.

Comment: @AndyHarris - pretty new feature.  I'm not even sure which compilers have good C11 support.  I mostly use clang/LLVM, which seems to handle it well.

Answer (score 5):

Here are macros from my library that work for types, rather than variables:

```
/* min and max integer values.  T is a signed or unsigned integer type. */

/* Returns 1 if T is signed, else 0. */
#define INTTYPE_SIGNED(T) ((T)-1 < (T)0)

/*
 * Returns (T)(maximum value of a T).
 *
 * Pains are taken (perhaps unnecessarily) to avoid integer overflow
 * with signed types.
 */
#define INTTYPE_MAX(T)                      \
    (((T)1 << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(T)-INTTYPE_SIGNED(T)-1)) - 1 +   \
     ((T)1 << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(T)-INTTYPE_SIGNED(T)-1)))

/*
 * Returns (T)(minimum value of a T).

 * Pains are taken (perhaps unnecessarily) to avoid integer overflow
 * with signed types.
 * assert: twos complement architecture
 */
#define INTTYPE_MIN(T) ((T)(-INTTYPE_MAX(T)-1))
```

Edit:
Adapting these to the question:

```
/* min and max integer values.  V is a signed or unsigned integer value. */

/* Returns 1 if V has signed type, else 0. */
#define INT_VALUE_SIGNED(V) ((V)-(V)-1 < 0)

/*
 * Returns maximum value for V's type.
 *
 * Pains are taken (perhaps unnecessarily) to avoid integer overflow
 * with signed types.
 */
#define INT_VALUE_MAX(V)                        \
    (((V)-(V)+1 << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(V)-INT_VALUE_SIGNED(V)-1)) - 1 +    \
     ((V)-(V)+1 << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(V)-INT_VALUE_SIGNED(V)-1)))

/*
 * Returns minimum value for V's type.

 * Pains are taken (perhaps unnecessarily) to avoid integer overflow
 * with signed types.
 * assert: twos complement architecture
 */
#define INT_VALUE_MIN(V) (-INT_VALUE_MAX(V)-1)
```

Afterthought: These invoke UB if V is a variable, or an expression containing variables, that have not been assigned a value ... which is the case in the question as asked. They are likely to work on many implementations, but the C standard doesn't guarantee it, and they will certainly fail on an implementation that initializes uninitialized variables with trap values.

Comment: +1 for taking pains to avoid overflow and generality. -0.2 for tacitly assuming that no implementation is mad enough to have integer types with padding bits. Rounding up, though.

Comment: `INT_VALUE_SIGNED()` typically returns 1 for all of the following arguments: `(signed char)1`, `(unsigned char)1`, `(short)1` and `(unsigned short)1` because of `[unsigned] char/short` promotion to `signed int`. It will give "expected" results for `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` when they are the same size as `int`. Good answer otherwise, +1.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Good catch. Any ideas for fixing that?

Comment: I've found one way for variables (lvalues), but not for (r)values. I don't think you can fix that in C99- if you work with rvalues. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a function that does this, but you can create some macros that do this.

If you have C11 you can use [_Generic](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html):

```
#define maxvalue(x) \
  _Generic(x, \
      char: 127, short: 32767, int: INT_MAX, \
      unsigned char: 255, unsigned short: 65535, unsigned int: UINT_MAX)
```

If you need C89, you can do it if you can differentiate between signed/unsigned:

```
#define maxvalue_unsigned(x) ((1<<(8*sizeof(x)))-1)
#define maxvalue_signed(x) ((1<<((8*sizeof(x)-1)))-1)
```

If you're willing to require the typename (or use the GCC-specific `typename`) you could use strings:

```
#define maxvalue_type(x) maxvalue_helper(#x "----------")
unsigned long long maxvalue_helper(const char *s) {
  switch(*s){
  char 'c': /* char */ return 127;
  char 's': /* short */ return 32767;
  char 'i': /* int */ return INT_MAX;
  /* ... */
  case 'u': /* unsigned */
    switch(9[s]) {
    case 'c': /* unsigned char */ return 255;
    char 's': /* unsigned short */ return 65535;
    char 'i': /* unsigned int */ return UINT_MAX;
    /* ... */
```

Comment: C99 doesn't have `_Generic`. It's a C11 feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a function does not exist in the standard C implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have been able to come up with a relatively easy-to-use macro, `SIGNED_VAR(VAR)`, to test whether the given integer variable is signed by modifying, comparing and restoring the variable's value (all that is only necessary for types smaller than `int`) while avoiding undefined behavior, specifically the kinds related to signed overflow and sequence points. Or so it seems. At least, gcc (invoked with `-Wall`) doesn't complain about me doing crazy things between the `&&` and `||` operators, although it didn't like the same kind of things around the ternary `?:` operator.

The good thing about this macro is that it should work with C89 and C99 compilers (`1LL` can be replaced with `1L` and `long long` can be replaced with just `long` (and `"%ll"` with `"%l"`, of course) if your C89 compiler does not have the extended `long long` type from C99) and it also correctly supports types smaller than `int` (`char` and `short`).

Once we know whether the variable is signed or not, constructing the minimum and maximum values is trivial and many have show how to do it. The macros `VAR_MAX()` and `VAR_MIN()` construct these values and return them as the longest C99 integer type, `long long`. I chose to return the signed type to avoid potential overflow/UB problems when converting unsigned values to signed. Since the returned type `long long` cannot represent the maximum value of `unsigned long long` (`ULLONG_MAX`) directly as a signed value, if that value needs to be returned, a -1 is returned instead, which after a cast to `unsigned long long` will produce `ULLONG_MAX`. You need to be a little careful here.

Here goes the ugliness. Hope, I didn't miss a bug.

Oh, and, of course, it's expected that the entire asymmetric range of 2's complement values is supported in signed types (e.g. min=-128, max=+127).

**EDIT**: I've forgot to mention that `SIGNED_VAR()` expects the variable to be initialized. Otherwise, reading it can result in undefined behavior.

```
// file: IntVarMinMax.c
// compile: gcc -Wall -std=c99 -O2 IntVarMinMax.c -o IntVarMinMax.exe
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int SignTestTestVal;
unsigned char SignTestOriginalXchar;
unsigned short SignTestOriginalXshort;

signed char SignTestRestoreOriginalXchar(void)
{
  if (SignTestOriginalXchar < SCHAR_MAX + 1u)
    return (signed char)SignTestOriginalXchar;
  return (signed char)(SignTestOriginalXchar - SCHAR_MAX - 1) - SCHAR_MAX - 1;
}

short SignTestRestoreOriginalXshort(void)
{
  if (SignTestOriginalXshort < SHRT_MAX + 1u)
    return (short)SignTestOriginalXshort;
  return (short)(SignTestOriginalXshort - SHRT_MAX - 1) - SHRT_MAX - 1;
}

#define IFELSE(E1,E2,E3) (((E1) && (E2)) || (!(E1) && (E3)))
#define SEQ(E1,E2) (((E1) && (E2)) || (E2))

#define SIGNED_VAR(VAR)                                     \
(                                                           \
  IFELSE                                                    \
  (                                                         \
    sizeof(VAR) >= sizeof(int),                             \
    ((VAR) - (VAR) - 1 < 0),                                \
    IFELSE                                                  \
    (                                                       \
      sizeof(VAR) == sizeof(short),                         \
      SEQ(SignTestOriginalXshort = (VAR),                   \
          SEQ(SignTestTestVal = (VAR) = -1,                 \
              SEQ((VAR) = SignTestRestoreOriginalXshort(),  \
                  SignTestTestVal < 0))),                   \
      IFELSE                                                \
      (                                                     \
        sizeof(VAR) == sizeof(char),                        \
        SEQ(SignTestOriginalXchar = (VAR),                  \
            SEQ(SignTestTestVal = (VAR) = -1,               \
                SEQ((VAR) = SignTestRestoreOriginalXchar(), \
                    SignTestTestVal < 0))),                 \
        (fprintf(stderr, "unsupported type!"), exit(-1), 0) \
      )                                                     \
    )                                                       \
  )                                                         \
)

#define VAR_MAX(SIGNED,VAR)                                     \
(                                                               \
  SIGNED ?                                                      \
    ((1ll << (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1 +                \
     (1ll << (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT - 2))) :                   \
    (                                                           \
      (sizeof(VAR) < sizeof(long long)) ?                       \
        ((1ll << (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) - 1 +            \
         (1ll << (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT - 1))) :               \
        (                                                       \
          (sizeof(VAR) == sizeof(long long)) ?                  \
            -1ll :                                              \
            (fprintf(stderr, "unsupported type!"), exit(-1), 0) \
        )                                                       \
    )                                                           \
)

#define VAR_MIN(SIGNED,VAR)                          \
(                                                    \
  SIGNED ?                                           \
    (-((1ll << (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1 +   \
       (1ll << (sizeof(VAR) * CHAR_BIT - 2))) - 1) : \
    0                                                \
)

int main(void)
{
  signed char sc = 1; char c = 2; unsigned char uc = 3;
  short ss = 4; unsigned short us = 5;
  int si = 6; unsigned int ui = 7;
  long sl = 8; unsigned long ul = 9;
  long long sll = 10; unsigned long long ull = 11;

#define PRINT_VARS()                             \
  printf("sc=%hhd, c=%hhu, uc=%hhu, "            \
         "ss=%hd, us=%hu, si=%d, ui=%u, "        \
         "sl=%ld, ul=%lu, sll=%lld, ull=%llu\n", \
         sc, c, uc,                              \
         ss, us, si, ui,                         \
         sl, ul, sll, ull)

#define TEST_VAR(VAR)                                       \
  {                                                         \
    int varIsSigned = SIGNED_VAR(VAR);                      \
    if (varIsSigned)                                        \
      printf("%lld <= " #VAR " <= %lld\n",                  \
             VAR_MIN(varIsSigned,VAR),                      \
             VAR_MAX(varIsSigned,VAR));                     \
    else                                                    \
      printf("%lld <= " #VAR " <= %llu\n",                  \
             VAR_MIN(varIsSigned,VAR),                      \
             (unsigned long long)VAR_MAX(varIsSigned,VAR)); \
  }

  PRINT_VARS();

  TEST_VAR(sc);
  TEST_VAR(c);
  TEST_VAR(uc);
  TEST_VAR(ss);
  TEST_VAR(us);
  TEST_VAR(si);
  TEST_VAR(ui);
  TEST_VAR(sl);
  TEST_VAR(ul);
  TEST_VAR(sll);
  TEST_VAR(ull);

  PRINT_VARS();

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/anl4a)):

```
sc=1, c=2, uc=3, ss=4, us=5, si=6, ui=7, sl=8, ul=9, sll=10, ull=11
-128 <= sc <= 127
-128 <= c <= 127
0 <= uc <= 255
-32768 <= ss <= 32767
0 <= us <= 65535
-2147483648 <= si <= 2147483647
0 <= ui <= 4294967295
-2147483648 <= sl <= 2147483647
0 <= ul <= 4294967295
-9223372036854775808 <= sll <= 9223372036854775807
0 <= ull <= 18446744073709551615
sc=1, c=2, uc=3, ss=4, us=5, si=6, ui=7, sl=8, ul=9, sll=10, ull=11
```

Comment: I don’t even… WHAT’S THAT `IFELSE` DOING? There’s a ternary operator in C, you know…

Answer (score 1):

Could easily be done using ANSI C 89:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<limits.h>

int main(void) {

printf("Max value of char: %d\n", CHAR_MAX);
printf("Min value of char: %d\n", CHAR_MIN);

printf("Max value of short: %d\n", SHRT_MAX);
printf("Min value of short: %d\n", SHRT_MIN);

printf("Max value of int: %d\n", INT_MAX);
printf("Min value of int: %d\n", INT_MIN);

printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Notice that you can include float.h and then use:

```
printf("Max value of Double: %d\n", DBL_MAX);
```

Though, it is less recommended.

Good luck,
Ron