# How can I determine the maximum value of a pid_t?

Tags: c, linux, size, pid

How can I portably determine the maximum value of the `pid_t` type?  There's no PID_MAX constant on my system.

(Note, I mean the maximum value permitted by the data type, not the *de facto* maximum value the system will assign to processes.)

**Use case:** I'm converting a user-supplied string specification of a pid to a `pid_t`, and want to make sure the user's input doesn't exceed the type's capacity.

Comment: Isn't `sizeof` sufficient for your purpose? (I'm not sure why you'd need that though, care to elaborate?)

Comment: `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` defines the maximum pid, which you can edit.

Comment: @KingsIndian, thanks.  I mean the type's maximum, not the system's maximum value in practice.

Comment: @Mat, clarified in an edit.  Are you proposing `#if sizeof(pid_t) ...` logic as a solution?

Comment: @pilcrow `#define PID_MAX ((1 << sizeof(pid_t)) - 1)`? Or if it is not guaranteed to be unsigned, `#define PID_MAX ((1 << (sizeof(pid_t) - 1)) - 1)`

Comment: On linux, `pid_t` is a `typedef` to `int`. So, you can define `PID_MAX` macro as `#define PID_MAX INT_MAX`

Comment: Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922775/1316213

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why do you need that in a preprocessor `#if`? If it's a runtime check data check, belongs at runtime. (@Shahbaz: POSIX says [signed integer type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html))

Comment: related: [How to portably convert a string into an uncommon integer type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/437802/4279)

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762040/c-get-max-value-of-variable) and [my answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769452/968261).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX (2008) says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> blksize_t, pid_t, and ssize_t shall be signed integer types.

And:

> The implementation shall support one or more programming environments
>   in which the widths of blksize_t, pid_t, size_t, ssize_t, and
>   suseconds_t are no greater than the width of type long.

So you could convert user strings to `long` and then check for overflow for the pid_t type using `long pid; .. pid == (pid_t)pid`.

Answer (score 6):

What I've done sometimes in the past is used a larger data type, and then when I convert to my smaller type, immediately convert back to the larger type and check that the value didn't change.

For example, say you used an int64_t instead, then you might have something like:

```
int64_t my_pid64;

/* ... parse string value into my_pid64 ... */

pid_t my_pid = (pid_t) my_pid64;
if ((int64_t) my_pid != my_pid64) /* check that value was not out of range of pid_t */
{
   /* ... handle error ... */
}
```

There's no great option for the larger data type to use.  "long" used to be the largest primitive integer data type but that's not true on some common compilers/architectures anymore--even for Linux (see comments below).  Meanwhile, the intmax_t type has poor library support.  The result is that int64_t is sometimes more useful in practice.

But, basically your options for a larger data type are probably long, int64_t and intmax_t.

Comment: "it still is on Linux" - it is on Linux for x64 (same size as `long long` albeit with lower rank), but not on Linux for x86 (same size as `int`, smaller than `long long`).

Answer (score 2):

Steven's answer is a good approach.

But if you really want to determine the max `pid_t` value without relying on undefined behavior, I think your best bet is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline pid_t get_max_pid_t()
{
    if (sizeof(pid_t) == sizeof(short)) return SHRT_MAX;
    if (sizeof(pid_t) == sizeof(int)) return INT_MAX;
    if (sizeof(pid_t) == sizeof(long)) return LONG_MAX;
#if defined(LLONG_MAX)  // C99
    if (sizeof(pid_t) == sizeof(long long)) return LLONG_MAX;
#endif
    abort();
}
```

POSIX guarantees that `pid_t` is a signed integral type.  This code assumes that the size of a signed integral type uniquely determines that type.  I think this is an excellent assumption, but I am not sure whether the standard guarantees it.

Any decent compiler will inline and constant-propagate all of this into non-existence, so performance is not a concern.

(Aside: In C++ you would write `std::numeric_limits<pid_t>::max()` and be done with it.)

Answer (score 0):

In one of your headers:

```
#ifndef PID_MAX
#define PID_MAX INT_MAX // or whatever value you see fit
#endif
```

you can also do it based on server/OS dependent definition based on Environment variables.

Look:
[Similar post : Maximum PID in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294133/maximum-pid-in-linux)

Comment: Thanks, @SparKot.  I'm not sure how your answer knows *a priori* that `pid_t` is an `int` rather than, say, a `long`.  Separately, I don't think that linked post is germane:  I want the data type max, not the max value the system will assign (which could be lower).